# Re-write the output of taxonomy_term_page() without hacking core

Tags: taxonomy-terms, theming

In Drupal 7, taxonomy.pages.inc contains the `taxonomy_term_page()`, which places a `<div class="term-listing-heading">` around the taxonomy heading output.

How can I re-write the output of [taxonomy_term_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.pages.inc/function/taxonomy_term_page/8) in my theme, so I can remove the DIV without hacking core?

I'm quite surprised that there isn't a tpl.php file available for `taxonomy_term_page()` as this would making theming much easier.

Comment: Give it a read: http://rarepattern.com/nodes/2011/theming-firehose-nb-designers-front-end-developers-new-drupal

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it with preprocess page something like this:

```
function themename_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if  (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && is_numeric(arg(2))) {
    unset($vars['page']['content']['system_main']['term_heading']['#prefix']);
    unset($vars['page']['content']['system_main']['term_heading']['#suffix']);
  }
}
```

in your theme's `template.php`

I believe `system_main` could be called something else, depending on your site setup.

Answer (score 6):

As it is a menu callback, you can implement [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) in a module to alter the menu callback invoked for that page.

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (!empty($items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term'])) {
    $items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term']['page callback'] = 'mymodule_term_page';
  }
}

function mymodule_term_page($term) {
  // Build breadcrumb based on the hierarchy of the term.
  $current = (object) array(
    'tid' => $term->tid,
  );
  $breadcrumb = array();

  while ($parents = taxonomy_get_parents($current->tid)) {
    $current = array_shift($parents);
    $breadcrumb[] = l($current->name, 'taxonomy/term/' . $current->tid);
  }
  $breadcrumb[] = l(t('Home'), NULL);
  $breadcrumb = array_reverse($breadcrumb);
  drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
  drupal_add_feed('taxonomy/term/' . $term->tid . '/feed', 'RSS - ' . $term->name);

  $build = array();

  $build['term_heading'] = array(
    'term' => taxonomy_term_view($term, 'full'),
  );

  if ($nids = taxonomy_select_nodes($term->tid, TRUE, variable_get('default_nodes_main', 10))) {
    $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
    $build += node_view_multiple($nodes);
    $build['pager'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'pager', 
      '#weight' => 5,
    );
  }
  else {
    $build['no_content'] = array(
      '#prefix' => '<p>', 
      '#markup' => t('There is currently no content classified with this term.'), 
      '#suffix' => '</p>',
    );
  }
  return $build;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I prefer googletorp's method as it doesn't need a separate module.  But your suggestion is great as it gives more control. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I recall, `hook_menu_alter()` can be implemented in a theme too; in Drupal 7, themes can implement alter hooks.

Answer (score 3):

Like the previous example, except it may be cleaner and more future proof to modify the returns from taxonomy_term_page in a wrapper rather than copy the original function wholesale:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (!empty($items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term'])) {
    $items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term']['page callback'] = '_custom_taxonomy_term_page';
  }
}

function _custom_taxonomy_term_page ( $term ) {

   $build = taxonomy_term_page( $term );

   // Make customizations then return
   unset( $build['term_heading']['#prefix'] ); 
   unset( $build['term_heading']['#suffix'] );

   return $build;
}
```

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it.